# Devise, Rails: Seeding users with seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Seeding users (model made by Devise) with seeds.rb doesn't work.

I couldn't see any error messages on console terminal after running rake db:seed.

```
user = User.new
user.email = "aa@aa.aa"
user.name = "Stack"
user.password = '123123'
user.phone = "01012345678"
user.school = 2
user.region = 0
user.save

class = Class.new
class.professor_id = 1
class.student_id = 2
class.save
```

For experiment, I made another model Class, and tried making seed in it, which works fine.

Comment: Did you try the code in console and use `user.errors.full_messages` to get error message?

Comment: Oh, Thank you @Yang. I didn't know I could get error message. The error message said that password was too short. After making it longer, it works fine.